# How to dynamically create an auto increment primary key for item id in iOS?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, primary-key, viewdidload

I have a database storing list of items. I want to give id to each of these items and then fetch / update the details of item from DB.

I have used appcoda's sqlite DB manager and doing it in MVVM way.

So, how do i keep track of an item id or auto increment the id everytime? I tried to include id variable in viewDidLoad, but, it gets reinitialized everytime app loads. So primary key cant be unique.

How do i resolve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: so, what you want is to handle the autoincrement directly from the app, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NSUserDefaults for your keys, it never gets destroyed until App is Uninstalled,

suppose you have an id 'int itemID = 1'
you can save it in NSUserDefaults like so,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:itemID] forKey:@"id"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

every time you need to write these two lines when you want to update your id's count.

**Fetch value from UserDefauts**

```
int itemID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"id"]intValue];
```